# Any expression for the probability of a hard sphere in Boolean model

Tags: distributions, poisson-process

I am working hard on a problem of Boolean model. In a example of Boolean model, points are scattered in the plane according to a homogeneous Poisson process of intensity λ. On each of these points a disc of fixed radius r is placed.

My question is: What is the probability if a new disc of radius rh is placed without any contact of the existing discs in this Boolean model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add this as a second answer, as I'll take a different approach.

Here we do not make any requirement about the overlap of existing disks. While this satisfies the definition of a homogeneous Poisson (point) process, it conflicts with the requirements of a "hard sphere model".

[image]

We require that there is no contact between the new disk (red) and any existing disks (grey). This is equivalent to saying there there are zero points within the red/pink circle.

If this area is \begin{equation}A=π(r+rh)^2\end{equation}

and the Poisson intensity is λ. The number of points within this area is given by

\begin{equation}N \sim Po(\lambda A )\end{equation}

So

\begin{equation}P(No\ \ overlap) = P(N = 0)\end{equation}
\begin{equation}=\frac{(\lambda A)^0 e^{-\lambda A}}{0!}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}=e^{-\lambda A}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}=e^{-\lambda π(r+rh)^2}\end{equation}

For **low densities**, we can use the approximation

\begin{equation}e^{-\lambda π(r+rh)^2} = 1- \lambda π(r+rh)^2\end{equation}

Which is equal to the area available to place the centre of the new disk, after subtracting the "exclusion areas" for λ existing disks. (see my other answer)

Comment: Hi Jeremy. The existing spheres can overlap one another. As for your new answer, only one new disc is added. So I guess your answer might be exp(−λπr2−πrh2)?

Comment: My answer is for one new disk

Comment: But you can think of the problem as having the new disk already there and then adding the existing disks! I don't see why it should become exp(−λπr2−πrh2)

Comment: BTW, I'm confident in the answer at low densities, as this relates to research I did on hard sphere models, many years ago! The concept of exclusion spheres is important.

Comment: "having the new disk already there and then adding the existing disks". Interesting idea! Now I understand your reasoning. I guess it will maintain the similar form even if r is not fixed. I will try this formulae with simulated image. The most plausible answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I post another question similar to this. I wonder if anyone is interested? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381792/coverage-of-a-boolean-model

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so apologies for an incomplete answer.

Can you assume the existing discs do not overlap, being hard spheres?

If so, the probability the new disc does not overlap is related to the area left over after subtracting the "exclusion area" of each existing disc.

\begin{equation}
\pi( r + rh)^2
\end{equation}

To illustrate, new disc, shown in red.

[image]

If you reduce the new disc to a point (it's centre). The probability is related to area left after subtracting the exclusion areas (shown in grey), where the centre cannot go. We are assuming, the existing discs do not overlap, as per hard sphere model.

[image]

Finally, we need to consider what happens if the existing spheres are close enough for the "exclusion areas" to overlap. This can be ignored as negligible if the existing spheres are widely spaced. If, however, they are close, this becomes very significant.

[image]

Comment: If it's really a homogeneous Poisson (point) process, then I would think you cannot *guarantee* that none of the existing discs overlap.

Comment: Agreed. Even if you make this assumption, you also need to consider if the exclusion areas overlap. I don't think this is a simple problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Agreed if we assume sparsely-distributed non-overlap spheres. Yet I am looking for a more general solution especially for a densely distributed case. I guess it might be kind of exponential form of r and rh but I cannot work out the exact expression.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not the existing spheres can overlap with each other?

Comment: Hi, guys. I have a new question on a similar topic of Poisson distribution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322425/the-probability-of-disc-that-fully-overlaps-discs-in-a-boolean-modelHope you