# The probability of disc that fully overlaps discs in a Boolean model

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process, point-process

In a example of Boolean model, points are scattered in the plane according to a homogeneous Poisson process of intensity $λ$. On each of these points a disc of fixed radius $r$ is placed.

Similar to the question posted before: [Any expression for the probability of a hard sphere in Boolean model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275264/any-expression-for-the-probability-of-a-hard-sphere-in-boolean-model)

My question is: **What is the probability if a new disc of radius rh is placed without increase of the area of discs in this Boolean model?** That means the new disc is fully overlapped by the existing discs.